# Identify kernel module for analogue video capture card Multimedia video controller: Adaptec (formerly DPT) Device 9065

Tags: linux, video-capture, kernel-module, v4l2

I'm trying to identify a kernel module to make an analogue video capture card work on video4linux.

lspci:

```
Multimedia video controller: Adaptec (formerly DPT) Device 9065
02:04.0 Class 0400: Device 1044:9065
    Subsystem: Device 3344:1122
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=slow >TAbort- SERR-
```

uname -a:

```
Linux camhub1 3.16.7-35-default #1 SMP Sun Feb 7 17:32:21 UTC 2016 (832c776) i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: First I would try upgrading my kernel to 4.12.8 or as close as you can come because there have been many updates to the video for linux subsystem since your kernel was released.

Comment: That would be difficult. Shared platform. I downloaded the latest linuxtv build and compiled it. I think my ko's are up to date at least

Comment: well your kernel was released Oct 30,2014 how do you expect to get it to work?  If your video4linux subsystem was not built as modules you will have to rebuild the kernel so they are modules.

Comment: You download and compile the latest linuxtv build today, or before posting here?  https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/firmware/#tarball  did you check for a firmware for you device?

Comment: I look at the wiki and couldn't find a single device that was made by adaptec or dpt that was supported by video4linux.  I check the pci ids repository and other sources, and could find no mention of a device going by the 1044:9065 ids numbers.  The only match I could find is **DSSL DVS2 series card**  which doesn't match any supported devices either.  Unless the card goes by another name I can find, its unsupported and you will have to write the drivers yourself or find someone else who will.

Comment: Post a copy of the results from **dmesg**, but only lines relating to the tuner card or v4l or dvb.  Your only hope is that your card contain someone elses capture chip that is supported, otherwise buy a different card.

Comment: Yes I did download the latest media build from linux tv, compiled and installed. I got hung up on which module to load. I have not done it from git yet, but i doubt i will see anything that new in there.

Comment: Little in dmesg: [    0.196380] pci 0000:02:04.0: [1044:9065] type 00 class 0x040000
[    0.196432] pci 0000:02:04.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xe4800000-0xe4bfffff]
[    0.196445] pci 0000:02:04.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xe4000000-0xe43fffff pref]
[    0.196458] pci 0000:02:04.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0xe5000000-0xe50000ff]
[    0.196585] pci 0000:02:05.0: [1044:9065] type 00 class 0x040000
[    0.196637] pci 0000:02:05.0: reg 0x1c: [mem 0xe4c00000-0xe4ffffff]
[    0.196650] pci 0000:02:05.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0xe4400000-0xe47fffff pref]
[    0.196663] pci 0000:02:05.0: reg 0x24: [mem 0xe5001000-0xe50010ff]

Comment: With latest linux-next the only driver for such vendor is eSATA. So, it means there is and there will not going to be in nearest future any driver for this hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel maybe too old, and this might not work but you need to updated the video4linux kernel modules.

First, visit this wiki:
https://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Hardware_device_information

https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/

https://git.linuxtv.org/media_tree.git/about/
 To clone the master development repository, install git, and run:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_tree.git

make
make install
```

Comment: Have you checked sources for IDs?

Comment: No. I'm a linuxtv source noob. Roughshod fgrep may point to "cobalt" or "Atomisp". Lot's of usb models came up, but my card is pci

Comment: @DesmondCoertzen  Your device is unsupported, and has no signs of ever being supported.  Unless you want to pay a linux developer to develop drivers for your device it won't be supported.  The cost of said developer is probably 4x+ than just buying a supported card.